# ajax get boolean value from C# function T4MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a research bar on my website, the code for it is the following:

```
<form onsubmit="return IsValidCustomer()">
     <input class=" sb-search-input" placeholder="Chercher un client..." type="text" value="" name="search" id="search">
     <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="" id="submit-search">
     <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
</form>
```

As you see, it calls a javascript function:

```
function IsValidCustomer() {
    var name = document.getElementById('search').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: lookForCustomerUrl,
        data: {'name' : name },
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.value);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Which will call my c# function, to see if the customer I'm looking for actually exist. If it does, for the moment, I just want to show the result, which is suppose to be True or False. But I'm only getting the error alert...

Here's my C# code, in my controller:

```
public virtual bool LookIfCustomerExist(string name)
    {
        List<Customer> customers = SearchClient(name);
        bool returnedValue = customers.Count != 0;
        return returnedValue;
    }
```

The SearchClient function you see is working fine and the returned boolean is correct.

Thanks for help... I just want to save a unnecessary page...

Comment: is LookIfCustomerExist a code-behind method ?

Comment: yes it is, so is SearchClient

Answer (score 0):

When you make an ajax call from an aspx page to a method in the code-behind, you need to decorate the method with an attribute `[Webmethod]`.Also, it needs to be a `static` method. That means, you would also need to change `'SearchClient'` to a static method if it isn't so.

```
[Webmethod]
public static virtual bool LookIfCustomerExist(string name)
    {
        List<Customer> customers = SearchClient(name);
        bool returnedValue = customers.Count != 0;
        return returnedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still fails the same way, any other idea?? When the alert "alert(e.value)" pop up, it just says "Undefined"..

Comment: try placing a breakpoint on the method in the code behind and see if the ajax even makes to it to that. If that works, then rest is a piece of cake.

Comment: Oh no actually it doesn't even make it to the method.. It cannot resolve my url to my method, I think it's because my method is now static?

Comment: which is set this way: var lookForCustomerUrl = '@Url.Action("LookIfCustomerExist", "Customer")';

Comment: when it hits the error section, check what is e.message. It would give you some idea on why it couldn't make it to C# method

Comment: Still says "Undefined". If I remove "static" from my both c# method, it's called... But it still fails, and the error is still "Undefined"..